# Issue with setting up integration of DocuSign with ServiceNow using Spoke of Integration Hub

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am in a process to evaluate the capabilities of DocuSign by integrating with ServiceNow. If that works out well we are gonna take the licensing part forward for signup.

[Link to ServiceNow Docs for using DocuSign Spoke of Integration Hub](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-servicenow-platform/page/administer/integrationhub-store-spokes/concept/docusign-spoke.html)

DocuSign: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/building-integration

The issue here is : Steps given in the DocuSign documents and the relevant option isn’t present in DocuSign Sandboxed instance. Basically I am not able to get the Client ID and Client Secret.

I am not really sure of the significance of giving the Sandboxed instance if we can't do any integration.

[Steps from Docusign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HyjL.jpg)

[Snip from DocuSign Sandbox instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAW4m.jpg)

Please provide any points on this integration and way forward to get it done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do full dev integration with the Sandbox instance. First you need to know the Authentication Type to be used by your integration which you can read [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication). Once You know which Auth type to use, then you can either follow [Auth Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant) which will help you in creating IntegratorKey (aka ClientId), SecretKey and Redirect URI. But if you want to do JWT then you need to follow [JWT Auth](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken) which will guide you in creating RSA Key Pair and Redirect URI.